# java.lang.StackOverflowError in Binary Search Algorithm

Tags: java, search, recursion, binary

Could you guys please help me? I get the error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at binarysearch.search(binarysearch.java:22)
    at binarysearch.search(binarysearch.java:31)
```

(binarysearch.java:31 repeats like a dozen times).
I have been trying to understand recursion but I guess I failed at somewhere.

```
public class binarysearch {
    static int[] arr = new int[100];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        fill();
        if (search(31, arr, 1, 30)) {
            System.out.println("true");
        } else {
            System.out.println("false");
        }
    }

    public static void fill() {
        for(int i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
            arr[i] = i;
        }
    }

    public static boolean search(int value, int[] data, int start, int end) {
        int len = end - start + 1 ;
        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        if (len == 1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            if (data[mid] == value) {
                return true;
            } else {
                if (data[mid] < value) {
                    return search(value, data, mid, end);
                } else {
                    return search(value, data, start, mid);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: StackOverflowError ===== Infinite (or very deep ) recursion... Debug your code.. you will get the error..

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am trying to learn about recursion so that's why I wrote it myself ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from `search(31, arr, 1, 30)` You will run into

1, 30

15, 30

22, 30

26, 30

28, 30

29, 30

29, 30

29, 30

....

And become infinite stackOverFlow

So you algorithm should be

```
public static boolean search(int value, int[] data, int start, int end) {
    int len = end - start + 1 ;
    int mid = (start + end) / 2;
    if (len == 1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        if (data[mid] == value) {
            return true;
        } else {
            if (data[mid] < value) {
                return search(value, data, mid + 1, end);
            } else {
                return search(value, data, start, mid - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Off by one eh? Thank you for walkthrough and all ^^

Answer (score 1):

Try to change recursion calls to:

```
if (data[mid] < value) {
    return search(value, data, mid+1, end);
} else {
    return search(value, data, start, mid-1);
}
```